# A standard topological-connection exercise

Tags: general-topology

Prove that a topological space $(X,\tau)$ is connected if and only if every continuous function from $(X,\tau)$ to $(Y,\tau_d)$ is constant.

[$\tau_d$ is the discrete topology]

Proof.:

"$\Longleftarrow$"

$f$ is continuous, so $\forall {x}  \in \tau_d: f^{-1}({x}) \in U \subset \tau$. But since the function is constant I got that $U$, which for hypothesis 
is an open set, has to be all $X$: $U=X$. So the only "clopen" sets in $(X,\tau)$ are $X$ and $\emptyset$. Thus $(X,\tau)$ is connected.

"$\Longrightarrow$"

$(X,\tau)$ is connected.

I'll take a continuous function $f$ from $(X,\tau)$ to $(Y,\tau_d)$ but not constant: I want to get a contradiction.

Since $(X,\tau)$ is connected and $f$ is continuous, I got that $Y,\tau_d$ has to be connected (for hypothesis).

But $(Y,\tau_d)$ is connected only if it has one element $y$. So $f$ has to be constant.

$\square$

Is it right? Thanks to everybody

---

**Another try without using the characteristic function**

$<=$

Let $f : (X,\tau) \rightarrow (Y,\tau_d) $, $x \mapsto c \in Y$. Since $f$ is continuous, the pre-image of every open set $U \in Y$ is an open set, and the same for every closed set $V$. But in the discrete topology everything is open, so everything is closed,so I have only two chanche:

(i) ${c} \in U$, so $f^{-1}(U)=X$

(ii) ${c} \notin U$, so $f^{-1}(U)=\emptyset$.

So the only open sets which are clopen are $X,\emptyset$, so $X$ is connected.

$=>$

Let $X$ be connected and $f$ a non constant function. For example there exist a $x_1: f(x_1)=d$ and $x_2: f(x_2)=c$, $c \ne d$

I take a closed set $A= Y \setminus {d}$.

A is also open. I have:  $f^{-1}(Y \setminus d)=X-f^{-1}(d)=X \setminus x_1$, which is clopen since $f$ is continuos, and different from $X, \emptyset$ since $f$ is not constant.

So I got a set which is clopen, but different from $X,\emptyset$, which is a contradiction, becuase I supposed $X$ connected.

$\square$

Comment: ($\Leftarrow$) Not clear - the essential point of this part of the proof is going to be to *construct* *some* discrete space $Y$ and some continuous function $f : X \to Y$ such that $f^{-1}(\{ y \}) = U$, for every clopen $U \subseteq X$.  $\Rightarrow$ You can only conclude $Y$ is connected if $f$ is also surjective, which isn't always going to be the case.

Comment: thanks for your answer... why is U  a clopen? I know it must be an open set because $f$ is continuos...

Comment: If you're going to use the "clopen set" definition of connectedness, then to prove $X$ is connected, you need to show every clopen subset of $X$ is either $\emptyset$ or all of $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems. When you are proving the first implication, you state that $f^{-1}(x)\in U\subset\tau$. Problem: you don't say what $U$ is. So, there is no way of saying if this is correct or not.

As for the reverse implication: It is not correct. Do you really think that you can prove that $Y$ has a single element? What happens is that the topology on $f(X)$ is the discrete topology and, since $f(X)$ is connected, then it must consist of a single element.

**Added note:** I shall prove the first implication proving that if $(X,\tau)$ is *not* connected, then there is a non-constant continuous function from $X$ into a discrete topological space. Let $U$ be a clopen subset of $X$ such that $U\neq X,\emptyset$. Then the function $\chi_U\colon X\longrightarrow\{0,1\}$ (the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function) of the set $U$) is continuous (for the discrete topology on $\{0,1\}$) and non-constant (since $\chi_U(x)=1$ if $x\in U$ and $\chi_U(x)=0$ otherwise).

Comment: thanks for the answer!

for the first implication I only know that $U$ has to be an open set in $X$...why is it a clopen?

Comment: @feddy Your comment is meaningless. You wrote something about a thing called $U$. Therefore, you must tell us what $U$ is. Otherwise, we are unable to detremine how good your proof is.

Comment: With $U$ I wanted to write a generic open set on $X$. But since $f$ is constant, every element is mapped to the same and so I thought that $U=X$.

Comment: @feddy But $U$ cannot be a *generic* open set on $X$, since $U=f^{-1}(x)$. Therefore it is a very *specific* open set on $X$.

Comment: Is it all $X$? 
Sorry but I'm going crazy... I don't want to sick you.

Comment: @feddy No; it depends on $x$. Besides, there is another problem with your proof. It starts with “$f$ is continuous”. WHat is $f$? It's the same problem again. You start to speak about a thing without telling us what that thing is. Look, do you want me to tell how I would do it?

Comment: Oh... okay. I can't really move now... I'm stuck

Comment: @feddy I have edited my reply. Please tell me what you think.

Comment: Oh... I couldn't image to use the characteristic function... thanks so much for your help